# How to change the source code when called zend_compile_file() before it is parsed?

Tags: php, c

I am replacing `zend_compile_string()` for code pre-processing, which then pass to the original `zend_compile_string()`.

It works.

But I also need code pre-process obtained from the files (`_include/require`, `php <file.php>`).
Zend provides the ability to replace `zend_compile_file()`, but the source text is available only inside `open_file_for_scanning()` (`zend_stream_fixup(file_handle, &buf, &size TSRMLS_CC)`), which is not accessible from the extension.

How can I change the code before being sent to `zendparse()`?

---

**Edit**: I found a solution:

```
zend_op_array* ext_zend_compile_file(zend_file_handle *file_handle, int type TSRMLS_DC)
{
    char *buf;
    size_t size;
    if (zend_stream_fixup(file_handle, &buf, &size TSRMLS_CC) == FAILURE) {
        return NULL;
    }

    char *res;
    size_t res_size;
    // My code that uses file_handle->handle.stream.mmap.buf/len is read-only and filling res/res_size

    file_handle->handle.stream.mmap.buf = res;
    file_handle->handle.stream.mmap.len = res_size;

    return ext_orig_zend_compile_file(file_handle, type TSRMLS_CC);
}
```